# Feeling stupid while trying to implement lazy partitioning in Python

Tags: python, iterator, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to implement lazy partitioning of an iterator object that yields slices of the iterator when a function on an element of the iterator changes values. This would mimick the behavior of Clojure's partition-by (although the semantics of the output would be different, since Python would genuinely "consume" the elements). My implementation is optimal in the number of operations it performs but not in memory it requires. I don't see why a good implementation would need more than O(1) memory, but my implementation takes up O(k) memory, where k is the size of the partition. I would like to be able to handle cases where k is large. Does anyone know of a good implementation?

The correct behavior should be something like

```
>>>unagi = [-1, 3, 4, 7, -2, 1, -3, -5]
>>> parts = partitionby(lambda x: x < 0,unagi)
>>> print [[y for y in x] for x in parts]
[[-1], [3, 4, 7], [-2], [1], [-3, -5]]
```

Here is my current version

```
from itertools import *

def partitionby(f,iterable):
    seq = iter(iterable)
    current = next(seq)
    justseen = next(seq)
    partition = iter([current])
    while True:
        if f(current) == f(justseen): 
            partition = chain(partition,iter([justseen]))
            try:
                justseen = next(seq)
            except StopIteration:
                yield partition
                break
        else:
            yield partition
            current = justseen
            partition = iter([])
```

Comment: note that "partition" usually refers to the functional operation of splitting a iterable in two parts given a function, so your name may be confusing. http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputlist/partition_f.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not [reuse `groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)? I think it is O(1).

```
def partitionby(f, iterable):
    return (g[1] for g in groupby(iterable, f))
```

The difference of `groupby`'s implementation with yours is that the `partition` is a specialized iterator object, instead of a `chain` of `chain` of `chain` ...

Comment: Thanks KennyTM! I guess I need to spend some time getting to know itertools. It is O(1) in space.

Comment: well, it usually looks like (g for (k, g) in groupby(iterable, f))

Answer (score 0):

it was bugging me that `partition` could be a normal list and not an iterator i.e.:

```
partition = iter([current])
partition = chain(partition,iter([justseen]))
partition = iter([])
```

could be:

```
partition = [current]
partition.append(justseen)
partition = []
```